# Restrict extent and Zoom in OpenLayers3 upto 1 mile

Tags: openlayers

I need to restrict map to a certain extent plus one mile. How to do that?

here is my code

```
    map.setView(view);

    map.getView().fit(bbox, map.getSize());

    view = new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:27700',
        center: center,
        extent: bbox,
        resolutions: {/* list of resolutions*/},
        resolution: {/* resolution value*/}
    });

    map.setView(view);
```

The `bbox` is bounding box for the extent.